How to get the Circulating supply, lp supply and lp burned details of any token in solana web3 js and raydium sdk i am using typescript and javascript
I am working on a solana and raydium project need to know how to get the lp supply, lp burned and circulating supply of a spl-token?

You can get the current supply of a token using the getTokenSupply RPC endpoint: https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettokensupply
There's no difference between "circulating" and "non-circulating" for SPL tokens, and if you want to see how much has been burned, you'll need to get all transactions on the token mint using getSignaturesForAddress and getTransaction and check for burns (https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/getsignaturesforaddress and https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettransaction)
